# Validating a graph/image in Karate framework?

Tags: ui-automation, karate

I have a scenario where the need is to validate some records displayed on the graph which is generally an image. Hence, there aren't any locators to those inputs, the image can be detected as present or not but the contents inside it is what I am now interested in. Regarding which OCR could be an approach.

Just wanted to know if Karate provides any inbuilt library for such needs or I am wrong with my approach?
Any suggestions on this would be helpful. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding `karate-robot` as a dependency and using the `robot` keyword: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-robot

And there is a section on OCR Locators: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-robot#ocr-locators

```
* def region = robot.region({ x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100 })
* def contents = region.extract()
```

This is not very reliable though, but you can try your luck. And do consider this a potential area where you can contribute.

Comment: Appreciate valuable and quick responses, will be honored if I can do my part in regards. Thanks @PeterThomas